# Apache Ranger vs Keycloak for authorization

Tags: authorization, keycloak

Iam new to both Apache Ranger and Keycloak. When I was doing my research I understood that, Apache ranger and Keycloak both has the authoirzation capabilites, added keycloak has authentication capabilities as well. Can someone help me compare the capabilites of Keycloak and Apache Ranger in terms of authorization capabilities?